# Need to split a thread so it runs in multiple threads. Also need to figure out a synchronized issue - JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

This program is about showing the oldest, youngest ect person in a network.

I need to figure out how I can improve it, so I dont get the ConcurrentModificationException. I get this when I ask for displaying more of these multiple time, like asking for youngest, oldest, and make it refresh to tell me whos the current youngest.

```
    public void randomIncreaseCoupling(int amount, double chance, double inverseChance) {
    randomChangeCoupling(amount,chance,inverseChance,true);
}


public void randomDecreaseCoupling(int amount, double chance, double inverseChance) {
    randomChangeCoupling(amount,chance,inverseChance,false);
```

This code is used in the network to randomly change the date outcome.

Also, I have this running in a Thread currently, but I need to fasten it, so I need to run each of the 'functions' to run in their own Thread.

The Class MainController is starting the Thread by:

```
    public void startEvolution() {
    if (display == null)
        throw new Error("Controller not initialized before start");
    evolutionThread = new NetworkEvolutionSimulator(network, display);
    evolutionThread.start();
}
```

When I click on any button ex a button to show me the oldest in this network, it is done by:

```
    public void startOldest() {
    if (display == null)
        throw new Error("Not properly initialized");
    int order = display.getDistanceFor(Identifier.OLDEST);
    Set<Person> oldest = network.applyPredicate(PredicateFactory.IS_OLDEST,
            order);
    display.displayData(Identifier.OLDEST, summarize(order, oldest));
```

I tried to make it like:

```
    public void startOldest() {
    if (display == null)
        throw new Error("Not properly initialized");
    int order = display.getDistanceFor(Identifier.OLDEST);
    Set<Person> oldest = network.applyPredicate(PredicateFactory.IS_OLDEST,
            order);
    display.displayData(Identifier.OLDEST, summarize(order, oldest));
    evolutionThread2 = new NetworkEvolutionSimulator(network, display);
    evolutionThread2.start();
```

But this starts main thread over and over when I press the button. What I want is that this specific function and the others when I press the cercain  button it has to start each of them in their own threads so I will be able to use more than one of them at a time. How shall I do this?

I can explain more if needed.

Thanks in advance.
My first post, so sorry if I didn't follow a specific rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the synchronized keyword -

**The synchronized keyword can be used to mark several types of code blocks:**

1. Instance methods
2. Static methods
3. Code blocks inside instance methods
4. Code blocks inside static methods

Everywhere you're using your set `oldest` you could add a `synchronized` code block like this

```
synchronized(oldest) { ... }
```

Comment: So like:        public synchronized void startOldest() {



or public void synchronized(startOldest()) {

Comment: The block needs to be around the sections reading (and writing) `oldest`.